# Failed to collect dependencies maven

Tags: maven, dependencies

getting this error when trying to maven install

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar) on
>   project AbacusLibraryServer: Execution default-jar of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar failed: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.1.2 ->
>   org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:3.0.0: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:3.0.0: Could not transfer
>   artifact org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:pom:3.0.0 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/3.0.0/file-management-3.0.0.pom:
>   Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 1]

i can see a lot of `.lastUpdated` files in maven.

tried using `maven clean` and then `maven install`.

i tried deleting all these files and doing maven force update using eclipse not working.

what is working is downloading every jar file one by one from maven repository already done for around 20 but there are still more and no idea how much isn't there a easier way.

also not using any proxy tried using mobile network and personal wifi.

Comment: Based on the protocol version I suppose you are using JDK7 or less. You need to activate TLSv1.2 via `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` could help...

Comment: using JDK8 and when i am manually downloading each dependency it is working but it is  not getting downloaded automatically.

Comment: See my comment...Downloading is done via Browser which works differently...